# Setting port in FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I need the user to be able to be able to modify  the port for downloading FTP information - but I can't find a way of changing this in FtpWebRequest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isn't the port just part of the URI used to create the web request?

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://10.0.0.1:12345");
```

Comment: +1. Beat me to it.  The port is the portion after the colon. (12345 inyour example)