# How to set port number using FtpWebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#, ftp

I connect with FTP using following code.

```
 // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.mydomain.com/websitefolder/downloadfiles/");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;


// This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myuser", "********");

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Now, I want to set port number but I don't get any property to set port number. Is it possible to set port number using `FtpWebRequest`? If so, can anybody suggest me?

If it is not possible to set port number. which port number use by `FtpWebRequest` to connect with FTP?

Updated: I am talking about port number 21 and 22.
Please guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting port in FtpWebRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024922/setting-port-in-ftpwebrequest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the port can be part of the Request URI itself.

Try changing the first line to this, replace **1201** with port number you want to use:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.mydomain.com:1201/websitefolder/downloadfiles/");
```

Comment: Sorry but why did you used 1201? Can I use 21 or 22? Please explain me so I will take care.

Comment: 21 is a default port for FTP control. Also, sachin clearly wrote "replace 1201 with port number you want to use".

Comment: Yes, that was just an example. You may use any valid port that the FTP server listens to.

Comment: @kiziu According to you, if I don't set any port(just use URL as I have used in question), it will use port 21. Right?

Comment: @NanjiMange yes, but bear in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876712/set-port-number-when-using-ftpwebrequest-in-c-sharp

Comment: @kiziu Thank you. I wanted to clear because now a days I am getting a serious issue. I am working on Windows Application. Above code(in question) is working fine in most 80% networks. But in some of networks, I am getting this error : "The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation". I still not found any solution. so I thought I should try by setting port. Please suggest if you have any idea.

Comment: @NanjiMange have you tried searching SO for your error and checking if any solution applies? I can see a few questions with your error. Or maybe it is a case of network configuration and firewall blocking ports used.

Comment: @kiziu I have done enough R & D for this as it stopped my new release. It doesn't raised in 80% of users. This is raised in 20% users. I can apply alternate options if this won't work.